# Setting up the Komodo IDE with XDebug for step-through PHP debugging

Tags: php, macos, xampp, xdebug, komodo

I'm currently running Komodo 7 and have XDebug set up on PHP 5.3.1, which is installed as part of XAMPP 1.7.3. All of this is running on Mac OS X 10.7.

Until I upgraded XAMPP (from version 1.0.1) step-through debugging of PHP in Komodo was working fine. I'd load a page in Firefox and the Komodo icon in the dock would start bouncing up and down, and I'd be able to step through my code, add breakpoints, etc.

It now seems that debugging isn't working properly. I'm confident that XDebug is set up properly, as it shows up when I run phpinfo(). However, when I load a page in Firefox, step-through debugging doesn't start in Komodo. Komodo does respond to an extent, in that information is displayed in the "Debug Output" pane in the bottom-right of the Komodo window, but there's no way I can see to start step-through debugging.

I've got a project I need to finish, so I'd really appreciate any help anyone is able to offer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get PHP debugging to work with Komodo (but I'm almost there!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632369/cant-get-php-debugging-to-work-with-komodo-but-im-almost-there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Hamish's comment above, this is indeed a duplicate (of sorts) of [Can't get PHP debugging to work with Komodo (but I'm almost there!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632369/cant-get-php-debugging-to-work-with-komodo-but-im-almost-there)

See that question for something approaching an answer.